# Ideals and Tensor Products

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

I'm reading Osbourne's Basic Homological Algebra, and on page 18 he has this situation where we've got a ring $R$ and a right-ideal $I$, and some left $R$-module $B$. He says $I\otimes B$ is not a subgroup of $R\otimes B$, but he doesn't give an example, just states "the free abelian groups and equivalence relations defining them are different". Well, sure, but the free abelian group on $I\times B$ is certainly a subgroup of the one on $R\times B$, and I cannot see how restricting the equivalence relations on $R\times B$ to just elements in $I\times B$ is going to make some new group that doesn't exist inside $R\otimes B$.

I've tried to make examples, but failed to find one which demonstrated this.

I've seen examples of tensor products which do this with more relaxed conditions, such as $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ since the latter is 0 while the former is not, although obviously $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ - but it is not an ideal.

I would appreciate some examples, and some idea of what causes it to happen.

Comment: Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $p$, s.t. $p$ is generated by 2 elements. Then $p/p^2= p\otimes (A/p)$ is a vector space of dimenson 2 over $A/p$ while $A\otimes (A/p)$ is just $A/p$ i.e. 1 dimensional.

Comment: @user26857: the actual statement in the book is quite precise and is about a specific example in which $I \otimes B$ and $R\otimes B$ are isomorphic but not via the natural map. So your conjecture about the most likely reading is counterfactual. I am now voting to close this question on the basis that the OP has done insufficient work in actually reading the cited text.

Comment: @RobArthan Do you own the book? He doesn't say $I\otimes B \cong R\otimes B$ (they of course are, but it's still unstated). The example at hand is actually to show $I\otimes B \not\cong IB$ in general, and that the use of explicit $r\otimes b$'s can be dangerous, because one might think $I\otimes B$ is a subgroup of $R\otimes B$, which he says *is not the case*. Well, "not a subgroup" to me is stronger than "$I\otimes B$ doesn't inject into $R\otimes B$ via the natural map".

Comment: I don't own a copy of the book, but I have read the page in question. You say you've tried to make examples, but you don't need to invent examples: Osbourne says exactly what $R$, $B$ and $I$ are. So the request in your question for an example is otiose: the example you requested is right there in the book at the point where you say the author "just states ... ". Hence my close vote.

Comment: @FireGarden: I will happily withdraw my close vote if you reword the question to say that you don't see why Osbourne's specific example illustrates what he claims it illustrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the "obvious" inclusion mapping $I \otimes B \to R \otimes B$, given by tensoring the inclusion mapping with the identity, need not be injective. Recall that, by definition, a module is *flat* if tensoring with that module preserves the head of exact sequences; but that is the same as saying that tensoring an injective homomorphism with that module always yields and injective homomorphism. So one should look at non-flat modules $B$.

For example, take $\mathbb{Z}/2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/4 \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2$. Both the domain and codomain are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but the non-zero element $1 \otimes 1$ of the domain is mapped to $2 \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes 2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

One example is the case $R = \Bbb{Z}_4$, $B = I = \{0, 2\}$ that Osbourne is talking about at that point in the book. In this example, you find that $I \otimes B \simeq R \otimes B \simeq \Bbb{Z}_2$, but the natural mapping from $I\otimes B$ to $R \times B$ is not an injection. In fact, $2 \otimes 2$ generates $I \otimes B$ but maps to zero in $R \otimes B$, because in $R \otimes B$, we have $2 \otimes 2 = 4(1 \otimes 1) = 0$, but $1 \otimes 1$ isn't in the free abelian group on $I \times B$, and in $I \otimes B$ we don't have this equation. ($R \otimes B$ is generated by $1 \otimes 2$.)